# Highlighting primary link for specific content types

Tags: 6, entities, navigation

If I have a navigation item called 'News' in my primary links, how would I go about highlighting it for all news content type nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Drupal 6 you have the choice of using the [Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) module, or the [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module, which is available for both 6 and 7.

Both modules let you define criteria for where nodes should appear in the menu structure (eg, based on node type, and taxonomy).